# 2005 Dodge Grand Caravan sputters & stalls after refueling

Tags: fuel-system, dodge, stall, grand-caravan

I fill my tank at 3/4 or 1/2 full and every time it sputters and stalls immediately when I leave the pump, just like so many other Dodge & Chrysler minivans I've recently read about. So, before I spend $90 on a fuel pump, I'd like to know:

1. Could the fuel pump be the problem?
2. Would using Heet and Sea Foam motor treatment, together, be better?

I've learned that this issue is not isolated but no one from either company has chimed-in to address the topic. I bought my minivan 30 days ago and test drove it on empty, but the dealer graciously filled my tank after the purchase. So, who knew? I thought I was getting a square deal.

Comment: Does the problem go away a while after refueling?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is the fuel pump. The pump isn't likely to "know" that you've filled up. What seems more likely to me is that there is contamination in your fuel tank that gets stirred up when fuel is added.

If the problem is common in these vans, it seems likely that it would be related to water – either condensation or possibly water getting into the tank somehow. If it is water a fuel dryer, such as Heet would probably help. I don't think Sea Foam would hurt, but it wouldn't address the water problem, so I don't think it would help either.

If the problem is condensation, then keeping the tank full will help (and the problem should be worse during the humid months). If the problem is water leaking into the tank then you may notice it getting worse when there is rain, or maybe even heavy dew in the morning.

If I'm right about the problem being contamination in the tank, then I'd also expect it to go away after the foreign materials have had some time to settle. The problem might also show up after a sudden stop or after driving on a rough road.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same stalling problem after filling my tank about 2 weeks ago and I took my 2005 Caravan into the dealership in Northern VA.  They replaced the gas tank at no charge and said that it is under extended warranty and I have 153,700 miles on the car.  I just picked it up today 7/6/17 and will let you know if I have any problems.

The parts that were replaced were: 1) CNPZX602-AA  Fuel Tank 14086001
                                     2) 55366298-AA  O Ring FU 14099003
                                     3) CNPZX603-AA  Canister  14039051

I have been reading online with folks replacing everything from Battery terminals, EGR valve, Crankshaft positioning sensor, ignition module, fuel
pump and so on. (When I first went to the dealership to ask questions at the service desk, a mechanic happened to come in from the service area and said right away that the gas tank needed replacing.)  Hope this helps others.